# Can you run Selenium in a web server?

Tags: c#, selenium, asp.net-core, selenium-webdriver, asp.net-web-api

I'm trying to setup an ASP.Net Core web API that takes requests then runs some Selenium automation. I'm running this in headless mode and I can get it to work locally, but it's breaking after I deploy it to an IIS web server. I just get a internal error 500 response. I've tried Edge, Chrome, and Firefox drivers. I'm having trouble finding any information about this because all the documentation is about running locally or running automated tests in a pipeline. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: I don' think your api should be running browsers on the server...  Running headless like running for automated tests should probably work, maybe the IIS user doesn't have access for what you want to do.  Can you check the web and event logs to find out exactly what the error is?  Does your server have the browsers installed and setup correctly?  Can you access the web server and run the browsers yourself?   Can you change your app to run as your user in IIS then and try it?

Comment: Yeah I don't like using Selenium like this, but I was kind of stuck automating something so I am trying this out. As far as the server goes, it has the browser and I can access the site fine from the server itself. I didn't see anything helpful in the event logs. I can see about changing the IIS user account. I'll see if that helps. Thanks!

Comment: Unfortunately we do not have enough information to answer your question. Please [edit] your question to include a [repro].

Answer (score 1):

I got it to work by changing the application pool account to be LocalSystem instead of DefaultAppPool. I know this is a privilegedaccount, so I'll see if one of the other accounts will also work, but for the time being this will work.